# Facebook Dialog in android Not coming up

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-activity

I am developing android application where I am using the Facebook SDK for android.

I want to use the Facebook share dialog:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
                .build();
```

When I run the application nothing happens, no dialog appears - there are no errors.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize first

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
```

Than Show

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
        .setContentDescription(
                "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
        .build();

shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

Finally call this.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: How to post title, description and image only without any "Content URL"?